# Ubuntu 14.04 screen brigthness problem in videos

Tags: laptop, screen, lts

In my laptop I have a very annoying problem
When I'm in Chrome or seen a movie and I don't touch the touchpad the screen attenuates automatically
It's annoying because the brightness automatically descend
Dim screen to save power is unticked, but it didn't fix it
I try caffeine too and it didn't works...
I don't know what to do for fix it...

Answer (score 1):

Under System Settings, go to Power. From there you can untick 'Dim screen to save power'. This will prevent your screen from dimming when you're not using it.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? if so, please click the green checkmark left of this answer.